# Limit a text column in an ActiveRecord migration 5.0 using the PostgreSQL adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having a migration that looks like this

```
class CreateQuestionings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :questionings do |t|
      t.text :body, null: false, limit: 260
    end
  end
end
```

Now when I run `$ rake db:migrate:reset` the limit is nowhere to be seen in my `db/schema.rb`:

```
create_table "questionings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "body",       null: false
end
```

Am I doing it wrong or is this a bug?

By the way, I am using rails 5.0.0.beta3 and ruby 2.3.0p0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`t.text` produces a `text` column in PostgreSQL and [`text` doesn't allow for size limits](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-TABLE) because `text` is:

> variable unlimited length

Since there's no limit supported by the database, the PostgreSQL driver won't look for a `:limit` option; keep in mind that you're saying `t.text(column_name, options_hash)` so you can throw whatever you want into `options_hash` and the driver will ignore anything that it isn't specifically looking for.

If you want to limit the column size then you can either manually add a CHECK constraint (which ActiveRecord won't understand so you'll have to switch from `schema.rb` to `structure.sql`) or use a `varchar` column (AKA `t.string`):

```
t.string :body, null: false, limit: 260
```

Also, your `schema.rb` is generated based on what is in the database, not what's in your migrations. Since `text` doesn't support a limit, the database won't know about your `limit: 260` option; if the database doesn't know about it, ActiveRecord won't get it back from the database when ActiveRecord is asking the database for schema information.

Comment: That answers my question. Also, your suggestion to use `t.string` works perfectly for me. Thanks a lot!